# what is order of execution of postmessage?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am posting message from my worker thread to main UI thread. I would like to know if i posted two messages MSG1 and MSG2 in this order, Will they both executed in same order in main thread at all time?or there is no guarantee with their order of execution? thank you.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I guess this might depend on whether those messages are different types and such, as one or the other might get "stuck" in the message queue of another process (hook).

Comment: You're not trying to post system messages like `WM_PAINT` are you ? Windows optimizes a few message types, e.g. it can fuse multiple paint messages.

Comment: no all are WM_USER messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put them in order in the main message queue, they will be processed in that order.

However, that goes for normal processing. The processing end may ignore the order and filter for specific messages or ignore specific messages. So if you have problems with the order, maybe your message loop processor does not work the way you expect it to work.